# C# MVC 2-3 Taking code from a .pdf, some text file and putting it into a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm totally new to C# and programming and was wondering what's a good way to grab data from a file and than entering it into a database.  Keep it simple please because I don't know all the technical lingo yet. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you can read this : http://jadn.co.uk/w/ReadPdfUsingCsharp.htm